# How do I use this variable in another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, import

My method store_useful_words take some text and compare each word in the entered text and then compares those words to some keywords in my database. The impWords variable stores those words that match with the database from the sentence. I have imported WebOutput to my database file and I want to use the impWords list to iterate through. How do I use the impWords variable in the database file?

WebOutput.py file

```
import DatabaseInteractor
import nltk

db = DatabaseInteractor.DatabaseInteractor()

class WebOutput:

  def __init__(self,text, impWords = None):
    self.text= text
    self.impWords = self.store_useful_words()



  def store_useful_words(self):
    keywords = db.get_keywords()
    tweetWords = []
    for word in self.text.split():
      if word in keywords:
        tweetWords.append(word)
    return tweetWords
```

Comment: In `def __init__(self,text, impWords = None):`, your code doesn't use or save the `impWords` parameter. Should it be there at all?

Comment: Can you show an example of this database that has imported `WebOutput`? It seems like the answer, assuming you've already done `import WebOutput`, is simply to call `output = WebOutput.WebOutput("this is some text")`.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `keyword` to `__init__` and then create instance of class. Code:

```
class WebOutput:
    def __init__(self, text, keywords, impWords=None):
        self.text = text
        self.keywords = keywords
        self.impWords = self.store_useful_words()

    def store_useful_words(self):
        tweetWords = []
        for word in self.text.split():
            if word in self.keywords:
                tweetWords.append(word)
        return tweetWords

# Using
db = DatabaseInteractor.DatabaseInteractor()
output = WebOutput('some_text', db.get_keywords())
for word in output.impWords:
    print(word)
    # ... do something else ...
```